# How to center a form using bootstrap in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

How to center a from using bootsrap in rails. I have this form which is linked to patients, and I new to center it, and maybe apply some other styles.

```
<%= simple_form_for([@patient, @patient.reports.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-control">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.label :date %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= date_field(:report, :date) %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.label :report %>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <%= text_area_tag(:report, "", size: "24x6") %>
                    </div>
                    <center><%= f.button :submit, :class => 'button_one'  %></center>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can add `<div class="col-md-2"></div>` `<div class="col-md-8">You Form Code</div>` and then one more `<div class="col-md-2"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about ruby-on-rails, but you can use bootstrap grid system to do that:
by dividing the page line into three divs 2+8+2 and put your code inside the second div,just like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2"><div>

<div class="col-md-8">
<%= simple_form_for([@patient, @patient.reports.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-control">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.label :date %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= date_field(:report, :date) %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.label :report %>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <%= text_area_tag(:report, "", size: "24x6") %>
                    </div>
                    <center><%= f.button :submit, :class => 'button_one'  %></center>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div>

<div class="col-md-2"><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use col-md-6, you are using half the width of the screen (unless the screen is small or extra small where it would use all screen). Bootstrap uses a 12 columns grid system (col-md-12 uses all the screen width). In order to center your form in a col-md-6 you must add 3 columns to the left. You can do it this way:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
```

If your form is small, you can play with different sizes depending in the screen size:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
```

This produces this (**in Boostrap 3**)

### col-xs-12 - Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px)

[image]

### col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 - Small devices (tablets, 768px and up)

[image]

### col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 - Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up)

[image]

### col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 - Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)

[image]

**NOTE**

Bootstrap 4 has changed screen sizes:

- xs: Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
- sm: Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
- md: Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
- lg: Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
- xl: Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)